# NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 103:

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using L5.2.

I'm busy trying to create a shopping cart and I've ran into a problem that I can't seem to figure out how it's coming about.

What is suppose to happen is after I've added products to the shopping cart, I click on the shopping cart link and I'm suppose to get taken to another page that says "getCart" echoed on the page.

What is happening is that once I click on the shopping cart link I'm getting the error below and I don't see how I could be getting that error if I'm only echoing out "getCart".

The error I'm getting is

> NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 103: No query results for model [App\Modules\Menus\Models\Menu].

My routes.php

```
Route::resource('/', 'OpenController');
Route::get('/{id}', 'OpenController@content');

Route::get('/add-to-cart/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@getAddToCart',
    'as' => 'product.addToCart'
]);

Route::get('/shopping-cart', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@getCart',
    'as' => 'product.shoppingCart'
]);
```

My OpenController.php

```
namespace App\Modules\Open\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Modules\Menus\Models\Menu;
use App\Modules\Portfolio\Models\Portfolio;
use App\Modules\Products\Models\Product;
use App\Modules\Open\Models\Cart;
use Session;

class OpenController extends Controller
{

    public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id){
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $cart->add($product, $product->id);

        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function getCart(){
        echo "getCart";
    }
}
```

products.blade.php

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ route('product.shoppingCart') }}">
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Shopping Cart
        <span class="badge">{{ Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart')->totalQty : '' }}</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

UPDATE:

I've kind of managed to fix it, but I'm hoping someone can still help me out.

I changed my route from

```
Route::get('/shopping-cart', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@getCart',
    'as' => 'product.shoppingCart'
]);
```

to

```
Route::get('/products/shopping-cart', [
    'uses' => 'OpenController@getCart',
    'as' => 'product.shoppingCart'
]);
```

Can someone explain why it wouldn't work with just the /shopping-cart

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't work because "/products/shopping-cart" is a different route that "/shopping-cart".
And since you call route "product.shoppingCart" you also have to have that route declared.

Hope that explained it.